# Dudas con el uso de memoria dinámica en funciones C

Tags: c

Buenas estoy iniciando a programar en C, estoy en el tema de memoria dinámica sin embargo tengo la siguiente duda al implementar memoria dinámica en C. La duda es cuando se usa una función que retorna una matriz, ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **create_matrix(int n, int m)
{
    int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    if (matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

            if (!matrix[i])
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    free(matrix[j]);
                    matrix[j] = NULL;
                }

                free(matrix);
                matrix = NULL;

                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Es necesario liberar la memoria que se asigno cuando se produce un error en cualquier iteración o no?

O es igual a tener:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **create_matrix(int n, int m)
{
    int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    if (matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

            if (!matrix[i])
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor seria que si lo hagas. Si, es cierto que el sistema operativo limpiara esa memoria por ti, pero unicamente al final del programa. Si planeas hacer cualquier otra cosa que no sea terminar el programa una vez `create_matrix` retorne `NULL`, lo mejor es que si la liberes. Para seguir buenas practicas y buenas costrumbres, lo mejor es que si lo hagas.